# My code displays what I dont ask it to

Tags: php

While programming/scripting on many occasions using PHP and I test my code in my browser it displays the number "1". I debugged my code checked many times but the number "1" always appear even if I have no numbers in my PHP script.

This images shows the number "1" before the array in sort values and reverse sort values

```
<?php

$numbers = array(8,23,15,42,16,4);

echo "Count how many values are in the array: " . count($numbers);

echo "<br /><br />Max value to show maximum value: " . max($numbers);

echo "<br /><br />Min value to show minimum value: " . min($numbers);

echo "<pre>";
echo"<br /><br />Sort values: " . sort($numbers);
print_r($numbers);
echo "<br /><br />Reverse sort values: " . rsort($numbers); 
print_r($numbers);
echo "</pre>";


?>
```

in which it shouldn't [image]

Comment: It is always a good idea to check the documentation for the functions that you are using if you are either unsure what they are, or it seems to be causing a problem somehow. Documentation for the function could be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), or by searching Google for "php sort"

Comment: Just as a general rule and something you should always keep in mind. If you wrote the code, the machine is doing what you told it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort()` and `rsort()` return `true` when sucessful which is converted to `integer` 1 when echoed.  Execute the sort functions, don't echo them:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo "<br /><br />Sort values: ";
sort($numbers);
print_r($numbers);

echo "<br /><br />Reverse sort values: ";
rsort($numbers); 
print_r($numbers);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I see thank you, i am a newbie so to speak. How to prevent it from displaying the integer of true?

Comment: Don't put the sort functions in the echo.

Answer (score 2):

You're echoing the result of an `rsort()` call, which should be a Boolean `true`, which displays as `1`.... so actually you ***are*** asking it to display that

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, `sort` and `rsort` returns true or false describing whether the array was sorted successfully or there was an error. The parameters are set up in a way for these functions such that you provide them the array that you are sorting on, and these functions modify that parameter directly, which in turn means you are modifying the actual variable that you passed in in the first place. This type of parameter is known as a **reference**.

To use this, then, all you need to do is call the function before you need to output the values. For instance:

```
...
sort($myArray);
echo "My array looks like this:";
print_r($myArray);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
sort($numbers);

var_dump($numbers);
```

`sort` and `rsort` return **true** (displayed as (int)1) if it's able to sort the array

See

## [Reference Manual `sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#refsect1-function.sort-returnvalues)

Comment: boolean true is what the function returns

Comment: Thanks catch on the echo and for adding more details : )